# Make GoogleAuthUtil stop asking user for offline access

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm trying to develop an app with client-side Google oAuth2.0 authorization for my back-end. I've done all the work needed on the Google developer console.
Google keeps asking for offline access whenever the app requests an authorization token with `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`. I'd like to give the permission once and for all, so the authorization process becomes silent.

Here is the code I use in my authorization `AsyncTask`.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String token = null;

    try {
        token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mainActivity, mEmail, "oauth2:server:client_id:"+clientId+":api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException playEx) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                playEx.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                mainActivity,
                1001);
        dialog.show();
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException recoverableException) {
        Intent recoveryIntent = recoverableException.getIntent();
        mainActivity.startActivityForResult(recoveryIntent,1001);
        // Use the intent in a custom dialog or just startActivityForResult.
        Log.e("Auth", "Recoverable authentication exception: " + recoverableException.getMessage(), recoverableException);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
        // This is likely unrecoverable.
        Log.e("Auth", "Unrecoverable authentication exception: " + authEx.getMessage(), authEx);
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        Log.i("Auth", "transient error encountered: " + ioEx.getMessage());
    }
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found something that could help any of you still struggling with this issue.

I changed the scope to something like this:

```
"audience:server:client_id:" + clientId
```

That's it. It works, even if the "plus.login" scope is not specified.

Hope this helps!